# What does the error "type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'XFile'" mean in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, flutter-image-picker

I'm trying to convert an image or XFile from image_picker to an inputImage for a different library.  The full error message is:
======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type 'Future< dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'XFile'

These are the 3  methods that I've been using to do this.  I've tried several things, but I keep getting this error.

```
GetImage() async {
  print("getImage");
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  final XFile? photo = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  return photo;
}

changeFile(XFile image) async{
  File? file = File(image!.path);
  return file;
}

getData(File file) async{
  TextRecognition textRecognition = TextRecognition();
  //final inputImage = _processImageFile(image);
  final inputImage = InputImage.fromFile(file);
  var result = await textRecognition.process(inputImage);
  print(result);
}
```

I call it with:

```
XFile photo = GetImage();
File file = changeFile(photo);
getData(file);
```

The error message says that it's on the line

```
XFile photo = GetImage();
```

I tried adding more functions, adding the async, and I tried changing

```
File file = File(image.path);
```

to

```
File? file = File(image!.path);
```

Comment: it says that what you are extracting is not the return type of your function.

Comment: I used runtimeType to determine what was being returned by GetImage and it says that it is an XFile, which is what I try to get from the function.  It crashes right when the camera opens and won't do anything after taking the picture

Comment: it's clearly a mistake from the programmer's side. But because of how the question is constructed. I'm sorry I can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert into Future method and  await for photo.

```dart
Future<XFile?> GetImage() async {
  print("getImage");
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  final XFile? photo = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  return photo;
}
```

Now call this method with await

```dart
XFile? photo = await GetImage(); /// convert it to async method, and this will provide nullable file
```

Comment: and view `if(photo!=null)...`